# igraph contract_vertices throwing type errors at different points during an interative process

Tags: r, igraph

Context: I have a path graph that I wish to contract iteratively; ie. at each iteration, take a set of adjacent points in the path graph that fit some critera, contract them together, and repeat iteratively until no points fit the criteria. The path graph to contract is roughly 5,000 vertices long, and the program iterates roughly 20 times at most per graph. Prototyping it via Rstudio worked just fine (and still works fine), however when running it as an Rscript it's throwing some errors, and in a different iteration each time (ie. this seems to be happening at random)

The first time I encountered the issue, it would throw a double free error. Again, this would occur unpredictably. I tried running on a different machine, however this threw a different memory-related error which I don't remember. I made a new miniconda virtual environment and reinstalled all of the requisite R packages, including igraph and tried again. Now I'm getting another error, here:

```
Error in head.default("2616", 1L) : length(n) == 1L is not TRUE
Calls: write.table ... contract.vertices -> head -> head.default -> stopifnot
In addition: There were 28 warnings (use warnings() to see them)
Error in contract.vertices(toy, mapping = vertices, vertex.attr.comb = list(new_residual = "sum",  : 
  VECTOR_ELT() can only be applied to a 'list', not a 'double'
Calls: write.table ... compressdata -> %>% -> eval -> eval -> contract.vertices -> .Call
Execution halted
```

Note that in "head.default("2616", 1L)", the number (here "2616") is always different every time I run the code. I have no idea what is actually calling head.default() since I don't see it anywhere in the contract.vertices() source code that I can get using edit(getAnywhere(contract.vertices())).

I'm running this on CentOS 7 machines with 1tb of memory each.

Here is the double free error with a few lines of the memory dump, note that the `Error: length(n) == 1L is not TRUE` is being thrown inside an igraph function (`contract_vertices()`) rather than my script. I see this error when I run it from a different anaconda environment that I have for another project.

```
Error: length(n) == 1L is not TRUE
In addition: There were 29 warnings (use warnings() to see them)
*** glibc detected *** /home/lculibrk/miniconda3/envs/lukonda/lib/R/bin/exec/R: double free or corruption (out): 0x00007ffffb3ea4a0 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib64/libc.so.6[0x3e9f275f4e]
/lib64/libc.so.6[0x3e9f278cf0]
/home/lculibrk/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/igraph/libs/igraph.so(igraph_vector_destroy+0x27)[0x7f8ccac45337]
/home/lculibrk/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/igraph/libs/igraph.so(IGRAPH_FINALLY_FREE+0x63)[0x7f8ccab5b24d]
/home/lculibrk/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/igraph/libs/igraph.so(R_igraph_finalizer+0xc1)[0x7f8ccac90976]
```

Comment: Without extra information the error is indeed not very informative. Have you tried running the script on a shorter path graph? You could also perhaps use `set.seed` to consider one case and see what happens after (n-1) iterations step-by-step if the error appears on the n-th one.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm pretty sure this issue is a hardware issue on my end or perhaps a bug in the package, so I'm unsure as to what additional info I can provide that would be helpful. I'll edit the post with some of the other error logs I've received. Mainly I'm hoping to get some help as to how to troubleshoot this issue, as I'm having a lot of issues even figuring out what's wrong.

I'm not sure if set.seed would help much here, as I'm not actually making use of any random values. The issue is the one showing up at random iterations. I'll give it a shot. Thanks.

Comment: Can confirm that set.seed did not affect the consistency of the error. Ran twice with a set seed and crashes occurred in different iterations each time.

Comment: I guess it's still possible, though unlikely, that something in the package ignores the seed. Perhaps `igraph` mailing list is a better place to ask. Or to wait for someone like @GaborCsardi to notice the question here.